# Best Buffer Size

Tags: android

What is the best value for buffer size when implementing a guitar tuner using FFT? Am getting an output, but it seems that the value displayed is not much accurate as I expected. I think it's an issue with the buffer size I allocated. I'm using 8000 as the buffer size. Are there any other suggestions to retrieve more efficient result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can kinda wiggle the results around a bit.  It's been a while since I've done FFT work, but if I recall, with a buffer of 8000, the Nth bucket would be (8000 / 2) / N Hz (is that right?  It's been a long time).  So the 79th through 81st buckets are 50.63, 50, and 49.38 Hz.

You can then do a FFT with a slightly different number of buckets.  So if you dropped down to 6000 buckets, the 59th through 61st buckets would be 50.84, 50, and 49.18 Hz.

Now you've got an algorithm that you can use to home in on the specific frequency.  I think it's O((log M) * (N log N)) where N is roughly the number of buckets you use each time, and M is the precision.

#### Update: Sample Stretching

```
public byte[] stretch(byte[] input, int newLength) {
  byte[] result = new byte[newLength];
  result[0] = input[0];

  for (int i = 1; i < newLength; i++) {
    float t = i * input.length / newLength;
    int j = (int) t;
    float d = t - j;

    result[i] = (byte) (input[j - 1] * d + input[j] * (1 - d))
  }

  return result;
}
```

You might have to fix some of the casting to make sure you get the right numbers, but that looks about right.

i = index in result[]
j = index in input[] (rounded up)
d = percentage of input[j - 1] to use
1 - d = percentage of input[j] to use

Comment: I'm curious what FFT library or algorithm you're using.  Back when I was doing it the algorithms were very picky about using buffers that were a power of 2.  I had to implement this process by stretching the signal and keeping the number of buckets constant.

Comment: yeah...Even this FFT algorithm is also having a buffer with a power of 2 chunk sample... The frequency am getting is not accurate. It really is difficult to tune the guitar using my tuner...:(

Comment: So when I ran into that, to get enough buckets I was using a significant chunk of memory.  Millions.  Way more than you can do on a phone.  Since I couldn't tweak the number of buckets by more than a power of 2, I use sample stretching. Basically you need to create a new sample that stretches the original into more buckets.  I'll update my answer to demonstrate that code